# Merge statement without UPDATE in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I  want to execute one Merge statement without any update operation. Only Insert operation will happen.

```
Merge target_table 
      using source_table
  on target_table.id=source_table.id
when matched 
<<THEN DO NoTHING>>
When Not matched THEN INSERT
values(
source_table.id
....
....
);
```

Can anyone please help me how to execute this in redshift. Or anyother alternative way to achieve this operation in redshift

Answer (score 0):

If you are just expecting to `INSERT` you could just go ahead with the `INSERT INTO` command

```sql
insert into Table_name(columns)
select columns
from table
where condition
```

You can check the doc here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Examples_of_INSERT_30.html